# Effect size measure for mxn Fisher Exact Test

Tags: r, effect-size, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I'm using the R function to run fisher exact test for mxn contingency tables (since my sample size <5; limitation of the chi-squared test). Along with the p-value I want to state the effect size. For a 2x2 contingency table I can state the odd ratio but what about bigger tables?

Comment: You need to define what your hypothesis is and then find one of the many statistics which you can compute from the table which responds to your effect size.